# VS Database Project: find references

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

*Visual Studio 2012* used to have a *"Find references"* option when right clicking a *database object* in a *database project*.

In *VS 2013* that option is no longer available. Instead there's *"Find Usages"* option and it does not work for me.

How do I get that back?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file, right-click the object name (ex. for "CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable" right-click "MyTable"), then select **Find All References**.

[image]

Comment: Problem is that there is no **Find All References**

Comment: It turned out to be a Resharper feature

Comment: "Find All References" is a VS feature -- no ReSharper needed -- at least with VS 2013 Professional. See screenshot.